# Need help on composing update query with replacing many string values in mysql

Tags: mysql, string

I've field in DB table which has string values as "principaux de l\'asthme : facteurs psychologiques, &eacute-; blabla &eacute tiques &agrave-;  blabla".

I want to replace string "&eacute-;" with "é" and "&agrave-;" with "à".

Can I have query for it?

Answer (score 0):

Check With This:

REPLACE(Column_name,'K','SA')

Column_name : Name of your Column

'K' - The characters which you want to replace

'SA' - The Characters with which you want to replace

If you have to repeat this for multiple strings use cascaded Replace function such as

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Column_Name, '3', 'test') , '2', 'test') , '1', 'test');
```

The right query to work for you is :

```
UPDATE your_table_name 
SET your_column_name = REPLACE(REPLACE(your_column_name, '&eacute-;', 'é'), '&agrave-;', 'à');
```

Comment: i've multiple values to be replaced by respective diffrent multiple values . like UPDATE `table_name`
 SET `field_name` = replace(same_field_name, 'unwanted_text1,unwanted_text2,unwanted_text3', 'wanted_text1,wanted_text2,wanted_text3')  like this i want

Comment: hi Avidan , yes but i've to write REPLACE many time which is too much